# How do I define a web service request structure?

Tags: c#, web-services

I have to create a webservice that receives a string as a parameter, and have been asked by the team to define how to structure the requests for the web service,  and where to send them.

Am I correct in saying:
https://www.oursite.com/WebServiceName.asmx?op=WebServiceMethodName?EmployeeId=string

Is that what they're asking?

Comment: I would suggest you look at DTO's/Services, like in ServiceStack. It is a very clean design.

Comment: I believe `asmx` services have been obsoleted by Microsoft.